# File Not Found Using np.loadtxt Even Though Saved In Same Directory Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am running Spyder in Linux Ubuntu and am trying to use data saved in a .txt file that is saved in the same directory as the python script I am trying to load it to using numpy's loadtxt function, however every time i try to, an error comes up stating that the file is not found which doesn't make sense as they are both in the same directory.

I am just wondering if anyone knows what this issue could be, other than the file not being in the same directory or the file name being spelt wrong in my code as neither is the case.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at how to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which will allow us to help you in a better way. For example, you could add more information about the error and corresponding code in the question by editing it.